# Strange "loading" error in Firefox (Drupal site shows loading bar at top of browser)

Tags: firefox, drupal, progress-bar, loading

I am hoping that someone could please help me troubleshoot this strange bug. I have no clue what this could be.

We have a [site](http://www.lambdalegal.org) built with PHP that uses Drupal for the CMS. (More [info](http://builtwith.com/lambdalegal.org)).

Someone in my office is experiencing this problem: When she navigates to our homepage using Firefox ESR, she sees a blue/gray loading bar at the top of the browser and the page starts reloading every second. It keeps reloading until you close the browser. The loading bar never seems to make any progress.

She does not seem to be having this problem when she navigates to other sites.

She is running Windows Vista.

[image: Loading Bar]

I could not recreate the problem on any other machine in our office in Firefox. I also could not recreate the problem on her machine in Internet Explorer or Chrome, although she claims that she experienced the same thing in IE and on her MacBook at home.

We tried disabling her browser plugins, but it didn't seem to help. It might have something to do with her browser settings, but I want to rule out any potential web problems before I write it off.

I tried to use Inspect Element, but the page was reloading too fast, so I wasn't able to get it to work. The Error Console scrolled through a bunch of errors really fast, but I grabbed a screen shot of them. The error that kept repeating was: "uncaught exception: Error: permission denied for http://static.ak.facebook.com to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger."

[image]

Thanks for your help! Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: Can you select the bar in Firebug? i.e. is it an element on the webpage?

Comment: I didn't try that, but I will tomorrow when she's back in the office. The problem is that it keeps reloading so quickly that the site appears to be flashing. It was tough just to grab this screen shot at the right moment.

Comment: Try to disable javascript and then load the page as well. See if you can tell if it's a webpage issue or a browser issue that way. Set firebug console to persist and see what calls happen there as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it tomorrow and let you know what I find.

Comment: Couldn't use Inspect Element because the page kept re-loading so fast. It still happens, even with JavaScript disabled. I put a screen shot of the Error Console in my question above.

Comment: Strange because I was reading about a similar issue and all says it errors in javascript. The Facebook plugin is all Javascript, so how could you still get those facebook errors if javascript is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like either a 3rd party cookie issue or something, not totally sure. Below the National Sponsors box on the right, there should be a "Find Us On Facebook" box with other people who like the page. You'd have to do some research, but just from the message, it looks like her browser is blocking Facebook from doing something. I "think" this has something to do with cookies, but I am not sure. However seeing as that box is not in your screenshot, AND the error is from static.ak.facebook.com, it's almost certainly the issue.

In my window I get the following:

```
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem
```

I've never used the Facebook plugins, so I wouldn't know, but I would guess it might be setup incorrectly on the page. This user is having an issue I would suppose because of the way Firefox is handling either cookies or facebook access. I'm trying to recreate the issue.

EDIT: I also noticed you have two `<div id="fb-root"></div>` elements. I know this is bad HTML and no idea how it would affect your Facebook plugin. This forge.typo3.org/issues/36363 page describes an issue dealing with how the element is positioned, yours looks fine, but it lead me to inspect your page and find both elements. Apparently the fb-root div is sensitive. Either way `javascript + two elements with the same id = disaster.`  Though, the bar at the top of the screen is strange, and still may be unrelated to this facebook issue. Other uses with the same issue didn't describe the page reloading or anything like that.